# Data resources for air pollution time series

Tags: data-request, geospatial, machine-learning, time-series, environment

I am trying to learn some Spatial Data Analysis before applying for a PhD in Environmental Epidemiology and Exposomics (I am a Computational Biologist). Therefore I want to work on a small personal project: I want to predict PM2.5 or PM10 concentrations starting from satellite data using Deep Learning.

For this I need a dataset of PM2.5/10 measurements. I read some papers on this topic and most seem to use daily averages from just a few stations (for instance, in NY (USA) there a just a bunch of stations measuring PM concentrations): I would like to have a more *fine* dataset (e.g., more stations per state). Obviously, I need to have access to historical data, but it does not matter the country or even the continent. As an example, the data from the [World's Air Pollution: Real-time Air Quality Index](https://waqi.info) are excellent in terms of coverage but limited in time. On the other hand, the datasets from the [US EPA](https://www.epa.gov/outdoor-air-quality-data) are excellent in terms of time-series, but limited in coverage. Are you aware of any open resource providing time-series data with good coverage that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

You can get PM10 and other air pollution measurement data from multiple locations in the city of Zürich, Switzerland

https://data.stadt-zuerich.ch/dataset?q=luftqualit%C3%A4t

The data comes either as

- [hourly](https://data.stadt-zuerich.ch/dataset/luftqualitaet-stunden-aktuelle-messungen), for the last 24 hours, updated every hour
- [daily](https://data.stadt-zuerich.ch/dataset/luftqualitaet-tages-aktuelle-messungen), for the last 30 days, updated every day
- [daily](https://data.stadt-zuerich.ch/dataset/luftqualitaet-historisierte-messungen), going back to 2012 (and also 1983-2011), updated every month

More details [here](https://www.stadt-zuerich.ch/gud/de/index/umwelt_energie/luftqualitaet/messdaten.html), including some [live charts](https://www.stadt-zuerich.ch/gud/de/index/umwelt_energie/luftqualitaet/messdaten.html).

[image]

Comment: There are jupyter notebooks based on that data available (German only!): https://github.com/opendatazurich/quality-checks/tree/master/luftqualitaet