# API for German Air Quality Data

Tags: api, germany, environment

The German „Environmental Protection Agency“ (Umweltbundesamt) provides air quality data for Germany on its [webpage](https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/daten/luft/luftdaten/karten/eJxrXZScv9BwUXEykEhJXGVkYGSga2Csa2ywqCQTJF7OAADyrwzo) and it is also possible to download data as CSV. However, as far as I know, there is no option to programmatically download these data, e.g. via an API. Does anyone know about a source for German air quality data which can be accessed programmatically, e.g via an API?

[image]

Comment: data from neighboring Zurich is explained here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/16247/1511

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not documented, when clicking on a link for a CSV, I noticed that you can use the endpoint as your own API.

```
https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/api/air_data/v2/airquality/csv?date_from=2020-03-25&time_from=1&date_to=2020-04-01&time_to=24&station=1457&lang=de
```

So if we deconstruct the URL, we can create filters to pass to the web server, which will return a CSV. That's an API.

```
date_from=2020-03-25

date_to=2020-04-01

time_to=24

station=1457
```

To programmatically access this API, you would have your code pass variables to the endpoint and collect the results.

I also noticed that you can replace `csv` with `json` in the URL to get a JSON response

```
https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/api/air_data/v2/airquality/json?date_from=2020-03-25&time_from=1&date_to=2020-04-01&time_to=24&station=1457&lang=de
```

---

To get the **metadata**:

The file that is returned `Luftqualitaet_DERP020_Trier-Ostallee_2020-03-25_00-2020-04-01_06.csv` contains some basic metadata in the filename.

To get an actual file of metadata, To get the metadata, I had to go to the Network view of "Developer Tools"

https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/daten/luft/luftdaten/stationen

The URL of the JSON metadata seems to be:

https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/api/air_data/v2/meta/json?use=measure&date_from=2020-01-01&time_from=1&date_to=2020-12-31&time_to=24&lang=de

[image]

Comment: Very good solution! Thx

Comment: “Everything is an API if you are stubborn enough”

Comment: Well, sure. However, given the huge public interest in air quality issues in Germany, I would have expected a more "open data" like approach by the Umweltbundesamt. Anyway, I'll get this working via the URL. Thanks again.

Comment: It's even got `api` in the URL, so mild reverse engineering is best practice, right?